# Ntru homorphic rerandomization

Tags: encryption

I am currently implementing NTRU keeping its homomorphic properties. I want to implement rerandomization like this:
Encryption: e = pr * h + m (mod q)
Rerandomization: e = e + pr (mod q) (Using a new random r)
Decryption is as described in the original NTRU paper

The first few rerandomizations work just fine but after some iterations i am not able to decrypt it anymore. What am I missing in my formula?
My problem might be a bit theoretical  for this forum, do you know any other forum to ask my question?

Comment: 1. This forum of SO is for helping with **your code**. 2. If this is a conceptialproblem this is probably best asked in the [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) forum. 3. If it is implementation based add your code along with your attempts at debugging and test data, IOW a [mcve].

Comment: Posted on [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53881/ntru-homorphic-rerandomization).